# How to Make Gutenberg Repeater Field

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Want to make a Quiz application on WordPress Gutenberg with React? The problem goes, when I try to make a repeater field of the quiz section. I use UseState to make the components Repeat the section onClick. But I can't edit the input field after repeating it.

index.js

```
import { registerBlockType } from "@wordpress/blocks";

import "./style.scss";

import Edit from "./edit";
import save from "./save";
import metadata from "./block.json";


registerBlockType(metadata.name, {
    attributes: {
        ids: { type: "array", default: 1},
        question: { type: "string", default:"Example Question"},
        answers: { type: "array", default: [""] },
        correctAnswer: { type: "number", default: undefined },
        bgColor: { type: "string", default: "#ededed" },
    },

    edit: Edit,
    save,
});
```

edit.js `

```
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import {
    TextControl,
    Flex,
    FlexBlock,
    FlexItem,
    Button,
    Icon,
} from "@wordpress/components";

import { useBlockProps } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
const { useState} = wp.element;

import "./editor.scss";

import QuizWrapper from "./components/QuizWrapper";
import TestComponent from "./components/TestComponent";



export default function Edit(props) {
    const [quizwrapper, setQuizwrapper] = useState([<QuizWrapper props={props} key={0} />])
    const blockProps = useBlockProps({
        className: "quiz-wrapper",
    });

    function addSection() {
            setQuizwrapper([...quizwrapper,<QuizWrapper props={props} key={quizwrapper.length} />]);
        
    }
    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <QuizWrapper props={props}></QuizWrapper>
            {quizwrapper}
            <Button isPrimary onClick={addSection}>
                Add Another Section
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

When I use <QuizWraper /> as a component it works fine on editing and changing on Question and Answer section, image has been uploaded below
but for the UseState hook for repeating the component {quizwrapper} repeates the section but doesn't allow me to edit and change the section

[Image of the editor WordPress dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzQub.png)

QuizWrapper.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Question from "./Question"
import Answers from "./Answers"

const QuizWrapper = ({props}) => {
  return (
    <div className='quizes'>
        <Question props={props}></Question>
        <Answers props={props}></Answers>
    </div>
  )
}

export default QuizWrapper
```

Question.js

```
import { TextControl } from "@wordpress/components";

export default function Question({props}) {
    function updateQuestion(value) {
        props.setAttributes({ question: value });
    }
    return (
        <div className="question">
            <h2 style={{ fontSize: "20px", margin: "20px 0 8px 0" }}>Questions: </h2>
            <TextControl
                value={props.attributes.question}
                onChange={updateQuestion}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer.js

```
import { TextControl, Button, Icon } from "@wordpress/components";

export default function Answers({ ids, props }) {
    function markasCorrect(index) {
        props.setAttributes({ correctAnswer: index });
    }

    function deleteAnswer(indextoDelete) {
        const newAnswer = props.attributes.answers.filter(function (x, index) {
            return index != indextoDelete;
        });

        props.setAttributes({ answers: newAnswer });

        if (indextoDelete == props.attributes.correctAnswer) {
            props.setAttributes({ correctAnswer: undefined });
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className="answers" key={ids}>
            <p style={{ fontSize: "13px", margin: "20px 0 8px 0" }}>Answers: </p>
            {props.attributes.answers.map((answer, index) => {
                return (
                    <div className="answer-wrapper">
                        <Button onClick={() => markasCorrect(index)}>
                            <Icon
                                className="mark-as-correct"
                                icon={
                                    props.attributes.correctAnswer == index ? "yes-alt" : "yes"
                                }
                            />
                        </Button>
                        <TextControl
                            value={answer}
                            onChange={(updateanswer) => {
                                const newAnswers = props.attributes.answers.concat([]);
                                newAnswers[index] = updateanswer;
                                props.setAttributes({ answers: newAnswers });
                            }}
                        ></TextControl>
                        <Button
                            isLink
                            className="deleteBtn"
                            onClick={() => deleteAnswer(index)}
                        >
                            Delete
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
            <Button
                isPrimary
                onClick={() => {
                    props.setAttributes({
                        answers: props.attributes.answers.concat([""]),
                    });
                }}
            >
                Add Another Answer
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Need Solution: How I can make the repeater section of the <Quizwapper>component and how I can make the repeater section where the <Question/> and <Answer/> components will work fine.

Comment: I think you should try innerBlocks. https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/
Generally speaking this is a clean solution, but not always possible, depending on what data you need to work with.